# cx_Oracle: Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect

Tags: python, sql, spyder, cx-oracle

I am trying to install cx_Oracle to my Spyder but I get this error: 
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect

Unfortunately I can't find any solution in the net, or how to tackle this error. I came across to this: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3383 but I don't see the solution there either (if someone does please let me know).

My Spyder version is 3.2.4, my anaconda version 3.6.3 and my SQL Oracle 4.0.3.16 (not sure the latter matters at this stage though).

If any way there is another package I can use to connect to SQL Oracle please let me know.

Many thanks!

Comment: How are you installing?  Details matter.

Comment: hi Christopher, i am using a proxy install that the company gave me (not sure i can write it here) after trying to import cx_Oracle and got the message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'     Thank you

Comment: I presume you are running on Windows? If so, this is a known issue which currently has no solution....but it also can safely be ignored as far as I know. At least, I've ignored it after reading through the issue you referenced some time ago!